# Displaying $_SESSION['name'] and $_SESSION['surname']

Tags: php

I am just trying to display name and surname by session. But,they returned 0. I don't understand why it returned 0 even though both of them are string. There is nothing interesting with the codes;

```
<?php 

    echo   $_SESSION['name']+ ""+$_SESSION['surname'];

?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The period (`.`) is the string concatenation operator in PHP.

By using the addition operator (`+`), you are coercing the operands to numbers, of which their value is `0`. And obviously, `0 + 0 + 0 = 0`.

What you want is...

```
echo $_SESSION['name'] . $_SESSION['surname'];
```

I removed the empty string in the middle because it won't do anything. Perhaps you meant a space?

Comment: But, why did it return a number,0? I mean it worked well without error.Why?

Comment: @user I have explained that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $_SESSION['name'] ." ". $_SESSION['surname'];
```

Output will be like Name Surname for example : *Mohit Bumb*.